# Shared Drives Intermittently Dropping

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have an issue with most of my clients (Win7 and WinXP) accessing the Shared Drives. I have brand new Windows 2012 R2 Server acting as the DC, File Server, DNS, and DCHP. Almost all users are reporting that they cannot access the shared drive while using their computer (not idle). The connection will be re-establish by restart or re-mapping the drives. All the mapped drives are manually connected via command line with persistent enabled (no login script or GPO). Also, whenever they lost connection to the share drives they cannot access the internet.

After surfing the internet, I found some similar issues and applied the changes but still having the issue.
Current Configuration on the server:

- NO external DNS configured on the DC
- All Clients are registered on the DNS
- DNS Interface Set to All IP Addresses
- Dynamic Updates set to Secure
- DNS Properties - Security Tab - Authenticated Users is present with Create all Child Objects
- No Secondary DNS Server
- All Clients does not have any external DNS
- NIC Power Management is set not turn off the device
- Applied this command on all machines "Net Server /autodisconnect -1"

During the initial setup, I set the static IP of the server with proper IP and added an external DNS (4.2.2.2). Another article I came across after doing a lot of research says that if you add an external DNS(during the initial setup), you will have some similar issues with shared drives dropping.

I really believe that the issue is the DNS but I cannot figure out what needs to be change to resolve the issue. On the article I read, he installed a secondary DNS server and that resolves the issue. I want to set a secondary DNS server using one of my server (on the same network and IP) but with little knowledge setting a secondary server I am having issue.

Please HELP!!

Thanks.

Comment: I would seriously consider moving your file server role to another server.  Running SMB file shares from a DC ranks pretty highly on the "things not to do" list.  I appreciate this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail? If they also lose connection to the internet, do they have any network connectivity at all? Can the workstations ping the server/gateway/eachother for example? When you say a restart helps, is that restarting the server? Does the mapped drive drop out for all clients all at once?

Comment: @dbr - they dont lose network connectivity. They  just lose the ability to use the network resources like share drive and internet - pretty much dead but the computer has an active network connection. When i tried to ping the server, it didn't reach the server. Restarting the client computer resolves the issue temporarily. The issue happens  on random computers at random times.

Comment: So what network connectivity still works once the problem has occurred?

Comment: while the the computer cannot connect to the shared drive, it cannot use any network resources like printing or surfing the net. Only when restarted or you leave the computer for 3 minutes or less, it will re-establish the shared drives.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it may be related to the GPO. The one thing I didnt think of.

https://support.cch.com/kb/solution.aspx/sw44384

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1139165-windows-10-losing-mapped-drives

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: Provide context for links: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.